# как связать две таблицы в php

Tags: phpmyadmin

есть две таблицы "countrys" со столбцами id и country, id для каждой страны своё, и  вторая таблица "citys" со столбцами id, city и countri_id, последний это id страны.
Надо как то их связать и сделать выпадающий список (drop down) со странами. При выборе страны выводится весь список городов этой страны.

Comment: вот еще дополнение. У вас есть страница, на которой показывается выпадающий список (drop down) со странами. При выборе страны вы инициализируете запрос к серверу, передав ему идентификатор страны. На сервере вы делаете запрос из таблицы с городами, которые соответствуют этой стране. Полученный список отправляете обратно на клиент.

В этом случае будет полная перезагрузка страницы. Можно сделать тоже самое с помощью ajax, тогда перезагрузки не будет.

Comment: как я понимаю список drop dawn можно создать с помощью jQuery или bootstrap, но как реализовать список городов при нажатии на страну не понимаю

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить про связь на уровне базы данных, то нужно установить внешний ключ (foreign key) на поле coutri_id таблицы "citys". Сделать это можно через phpmyadmin, а можно через запрос

```
ALTER TABLE `citys` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`countri_id`) REFERENCES `countrys`(`id`);
```

Если говорить именно о выборке городов по стране, то запрос:

```
select * from `citys` where `countri_id`='id'
```

Где id - идентификатор страны